# Probability of needing to flip an unfair coin at least X times if I want Y heads?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

If I know the probability of success for a set of independent events, as well as the number of successes I want (i.e. the number of slots I need to fill), how do I compute the probability of needing **at least** a certain number of trials to fill up all my slots if I don't know the total number of trials? Is a binomial distribution the correct approach here?

As an example, let's say I have an unfair coin and the probability of landing heads is $p=0.4$. What's the probability that I'll need to flip this coin at least 7 times to get 3 heads?

Comment: So you want the probability that $3$rd head will occur *on or after* the $7$th trial? In general: That head number $Y$ will occur *on or after* trial number $X$?  That sounds like a job for [*negative binomial distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Negative Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) is the distribution you are looking for here. The negative binomial distribution is a generalization of the geometric distribution, which models the number of trials before a single success is attained. It takes two parameters: $p$, the probability of success in each independent trial, and $k$, the number of desired successes. In your case, the probability that you will need to flip more than $x$ coins with probability of success $p_0$ to get $k_0$ heads is $1 - F(x)$, where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of a negative binomial distribution with $p = p_0$ and $k = k_0$.

Here's another way of looking at it. If you need to flip more than $x$ coins with probability of success $p_0$ to get $k_0$ heads (successes), then in your first $x$ flips you necessarily got less than $k_0$ successes. The number of successes $j$ you got in your first $x$ flips thus ranges from $0$ to $k_0 - 1$. For a given $j$ in this range, the probability that you got exactly $j$ successes in your first $x$ flips has probability
$${x \choose j} p^j (1-p)^{x-j}$$
And therefore, the probability that you will need to flip more than $x$ coins is a summation over all possible $j$, i.e.
$$\mathbb{P}(\text{need more than } x \text{ flips for } k_0 \text{ successes}) = \sum_{j = 0}^{k_0 - 1} {x \choose j} p^j (1-p)^{x-j}$$
Unfortunately, there is no significantly nicer way to write the above expression. (One can write it using the incomplete beta function, but it's not much nicer.)

Answer (score 0):

The binomial distribution would be used if you were asking how many heads you would get in a specific number of flips. Since you have the reverse of this, asking how many flips you need for a specific number of heads, you should use the [negative binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) distribution.